# Is there any workaround using which we can install multiple versions of same artifact in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I need to install multiple versions of same artifact in maven and use both of them in the same module, but since maven allows only one version due to it the import statements are breaking for either of the version. Is there any workaround that can get help me install both the versions in the same module and use the imports from both at the same time.

Comment: This will most likely end very badly (except for the most experienced).  Could you back up a step and describe the actual problem that you have?

Comment: Why did you specify the surefire plugin? Is it related to the tests? In any case even without maven, if you have two different artifacts that differ only by versions, java application probably won't be working properly because it won't be clear which artifact to take. So could you elaborate more on your use case, maybe there is another (and more appropriate solution) to your issue?

Comment: Please describe in detail the situation you have and what is the idea and why do you need two versions?

Answer (score -1):

It's possible, but be careful. [Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html) is your friend (or maybe enemy...)

Suppose you wanted both 3.10 and 3.12 of Apache Commons. It might look something like this:

```
parent
    myapp -> commons-lang3:3.12.0
          -> commons-shaded
     
    commons-shaded -> commons-lang3:3.10.0
```

A multi-module project with 2 modules: `myapp`, and `commons-shaded`. `myapp` is what you already have, and can depend on one of the versions of Apache Commons directly.

`commons-shaded` would contain no code, but would use the Shade plugin to repackage Apache Commons into a package with a distinct name.

Suppose your application wanted `ClassUtils`, you would use `org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils` for the 3.12 version, and (depending how you shade it) `org.apache.commons.lang3.somefakepackage.ClassUtils` for the 3.10 version.

Because of the restriction imposed by Java, you cannot import both of these in the same class, because they have the same class name. If you have to use them in the same class, you can either import one and the fully qualified name for the other, or my suggestion would be to use the fully qualified name for both. It's more verbose, but when you have unusual situations like this, verbosity is often better.